# how can I vertically align a google icon within a button? (ie11)

Tags: html, css, button

I have trouble with vertical alignment of some google icons inside buttons. I tried to play with padding and margin but I could not fix the issue.

This is a screenshot of the problem: as you can see the icon are placed slightly higher:

[image: screenshot]

This is part of the html, each button is more or less the same:

```
<div id="mainToolbar">
    <button id="buttonPencil" data-tool="yes" data-type="draw" title="Use pencil" class="button" onclick="changeTool(0);">
        <i class="material-icons">brush</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

This is the css for the button:

```
.button {

    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;

    color: black;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    border-radius: 6px;

    background-color: #EFEFEF;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 4;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #aaaaaa !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

And finally the css for the div:

```
#mainToolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 520px;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;

}
```

How can I put the icon right in the middle of the button (both vertically and horizontally)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning along with translate to position the icon right in the middle. Be sure to add a `position:relative` on the `button` so that the icon is positioned w.r.t to the button.

```css
.button {

    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;

    color: black;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    border-radius: 6px;

    background-color: #EFEFEF;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 4;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #aaaaaa !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.button:active i{
    /*for push effect on click*/
    transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
}

.button i {
  /*horizontal and vertical centering*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#mainToolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 520px;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div id="mainToolbar">
    <button id="buttonPencil" data-tool="yes" data-type="draw" title="Use pencil" class="button" onclick="changeTool(0);">
        <i class="material-icons">brush</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

To explain:
`top:50%` with a `position: absolute` will move the icon down 50% of the parent's height. A translateY with -50% will move the icon up by half its height so that its aligned right in the middle by its center. Similarly with horizontal centering.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it works perfectly. Unfortunately there is another issue now: when I push the button the icon does not have the "push" effect anymore. It's basically the same problem I mentioned in this post (if you have time please take a look): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356458/why-using-transform-on-a-google-icon-inside-a-button-causes-it-to-loose-the-pus

Comment: What do you mean by the "push" effect"? Is it being done by JS? Can you add that code in the question you have mentioned above?

Comment: No it’s the default behave of buttons, no js added. As you press the button by default the content appears as pushed (it basically moves a few pixel to the right and down).

Comment: I made a gif of the effect I mean: https://media.giphy.com/media/pyhAVLYHxdIfM2Go2o/giphy.gif
after you add the transform it just stays flat with no animation.

Comment: I also don't see the effect by default. I might be able to figure out why its not working if you could upload a working code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, wrong post. To see the effect you have to remove the transform in the css. It will work fine.

Comment: @devamat Even with the transform removed, I don't see the effect by default in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Currently I'm using the code you provided and it works perfectly. I'm not sure why you are unable to see it; maybe something related to windows? I have windows 8.1 basic.

Answer (score 0):

Its Working Fine see snippet

```css
.button {

    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;

    color: black;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    border-radius: 6px;

    background-color: #EFEFEF;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 4;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #aaaaaa !important;
    color: white !important;
}
And finally the css for the div:

#mainToolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 520px;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="mainToolbar">
    <button id="buttonPencil" data-tool="yes" data-type="draw" title="Use pencil" class="button" onclick="changeTool(0);">
        <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you're using a fa fa icon; could the google icons be the issue here?